# Question on importing library's into python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and the imports that have accumulated whilst developing my app seem like I'm repeating imports. Please can someone advise me on development practices.

```
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.request import urlopen
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio
from gi.repository import GLib as glib
from gtk_assistant import AssistantApp

import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json
import gi
import sys
import os
import hashlib
```

Comment: EDIT: Please consult [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) first. That being said, you could compress your imports a little bit while maintaining the same code afterwards. e.g. `gi.repository` imports could be grouped, but I am not sure this is considered best practice. Ultimately they should work best for the readability of the following code. You could try if e.g. PyCharm's *Optimize import* feature produces something to your liking. I like to use `import ...` as much as possible, so that I know everywhere in my code, where something is coming from.

Comment: When concerned about coding guidelines and practices, the first place I look is PEP 8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports). TLDR: builtin imports first, third party imports second, and finally your own local imports last with a blank line between each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group imports like this if you want:

```py
from urllib import request, error
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import json, gi, sys, os, hashlib
```

However, the [pep8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) says you should have them on seperate lines so the way you did it is fine